# How to run AngularJS end to end tests on Jenkins?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, jenkins, karma-runner, angularjs-e2e

How can I run AngularJS [end to end](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.e2e-testing) tests on Jenkins? As far as I understand, e2e tests require a web server.

I can run e2e tests locally with [karma](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.8/index.html) while node.js web server script is running.

Answer (score 3):

Would also say, get grunt running inside jenkins using https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NodeJS+Plugin

it's awesome